# Azure Mobile Services - Alter User model on Insert script

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have a `reservation` model and a `user` model. In the insert script for my `reservation` model, I have the following:

```
function insert(item, user, request) {
    response.send(200, 'test');
    item.organizationid = user.organizationid;
    if (user.hourstoreserve <= (item.endtime - item.starttime)) {
        request.respond(400, 'You do not have the necessary hours available to make this reservation');
    } else if (user.complaints >= user.complaintsallowed) {
        request.respond(400, 'You are over your maximum number of allowed complaints this month.');        
    } else {
        user.hourstoreserve = (user.hourstoreserve - (item.endtime - item.starttime));
        request.execute();   
    };           
};
```

I need to make sure that `item`, which should be my new `reservation` that I am inserting, gets an `organizationid` from my `user`. I also then want to make sure the `user` has it's `hourstoreserve` validated, and if the `reservation` is made the `user`'s `hourstoreserve` should be lowered.

It seems like this script isn't being executed at all. The first `response.send(200, 'test');` does not send a response.

I am calling this insert script from my custom api similar to the following:

```
var reservations = request.service.tables.getTable("reservations");
reservations.insert(newReservation);
```

The custom API call works and inserts the reservation as it should, it just doesn't seem to execute my insert script.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you invoke the CRUD operations of the tables from the service itself (i.e., in the code of a custom API, scheduler or another table), the table scripts are not executed. There's an [open feature request](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/216254-mobile-services/suggestions/4180025-support-crud-table-scripts-via-the-js-table-object) to have this feature added to the backend, please upvote it if you think it will help you.

Another problem which I see in your code - the `user` object which is passed to the insert script isn't an item from your user model; instead, it's the information about the logged in user to the service (i.e., in the client side, after calling one of the login operations, that will be the user information it will have). That object doesn't have any properties about organization id, `hourstoreserve`, etc. If you need to get that information, you'll need to query your users table and working with it directly.